# Azure Blob Trigger - Processing Timeout

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking to use a Blob Trigger for a long running processing of a file.

I'm aware there a processing timeouts durations for and have seen 5 minutes for Http trigger on consumption plan but can't find any documentation if there timeouts imposed for Blob triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `functionTimeout` attribute to schedule the timeout for Blob trigger Azure function.**

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) to know more about `functionTimeout`.

[image]

- In Consumption Plan, Default Timeout is 5 Minuted and Maximum Timeout is 10 Minutes.
- For long running process that is **more than 10 minutes**, you can use **Premium or App Service** Plans.
- Set the `functionTimeout` in ***host.json*** as shown below:

```json
{
"functionTimeout":"01:00:00"
}
```

I have created a Blob Trigger Azure function:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function")]
public void Run([BlobTrigger("myqueue-items/{name}", Connection = "demo")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

- I'm let the function will sleep for 30 seconds by adding `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);` in the function code.

**host.json:**

I have scheduled the `functionTimeout` for 20 seconds.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:00:20"
}
```

I can see the function getting time out after 20 seconds.

[image]

- You can schedule the `functionTimeout` according to your requirement.

**References:**

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1900